# get p tags that come after a specific tag using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I'm crawling a website using htmlagilitypack c#:

```
i have in the source code of an html page

....
<p>this a p that come before h3</p>
....
....
<h3>this h3 </h3>

<p>first p after h3</p>

....

<p>seconde p after h3</p>
```

i want to to all get all Ps that come after

is there a way to use a where to filter Ps using position.

where (position(p)>position(h3))

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper method such as this:

```
static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> FilteredTakeWhile(
    HtmlNode root,
    Func<HtmlNode, bool> predicate,
    Func<HtmlNode, bool> takePredicate)
{
    for (var currentNode = root.NextSibling;
         currentNode != null && takePredicate(currentNode);
         currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling)
    {
        if (predicate(currentNode))
            yield return currentNode;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var h3 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("h3");
// take all "p" nodes while we haven't reached the next "h3" node
var query = FilteredTakeWhile(h3, node => node.Name == "p", node => node.Name != "h3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var htmlText = "source code of your html page";
var htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);
var h3= htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2");
var lineNum = h3[0].Line;
var p = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p").Where(x => x.Line > lineNum);
```